# Storing XML Document with XPath and PHP, tag info isn't storing in array like needed

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath

So, I want to iterate through the XML by the attributes of  and then print the  tags from within the coordinating  tag. This is the structure:

```
<emp salesid="1">
    <report>07-14-2015_DPLOH_SalesID_1.pdf</report>
    <report>07-17-2015_DPLOH_SalesID_1.pdf</report>
    <report>07-14-2015_DTE_SalesID_1.pdf</report>
    <report>07-14-2015_IDT_SalesID_1.pdf</report>
    <report>07-14-2015_Kratos_SalesID_1.pdf</report>
    <report>07-14-2015_Spark_SalesID_1.pdf</report>
</emp>
```

Here is the my code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

foreach($xml->xpath("//emp/report") as $node) {
    //For all found nodes retrieve its ID from parent <emp> and store in $arr
    $id = $node->xpath("../@salesid");
    $id = (int)$id[0];
    if(!isset($arr[$id])) {
        $arr[$id] = array();
    }

    //Then we iterate through all nodes and store <report> in $arr
    foreach($node as $report) {
        $arr[$id][] = (string)$report;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

However, this is what I get for output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
        )
```

... and it continues to iterate through all of the attributes of  tags, but never fills the array with any information.

If anyone could help tell me what I'm missing, I would GREATLY appreciate it. I feel like I'm losing my mind over what seems like should be rather simple.

Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to do this in a generic way, but not that difficult to generate a specific array structure from a specific XML. Iterate the `emp` elements, read the specific values and generate the target array structure.

Comment: I rewrote the code, but I am having some trouble getting it to store the <report> tag information like I need it to. If you have any insight, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  The code isn't working because of the second `for` loop.  The outer loop will iterate through all of the `report` elements.  So, `node` is a `report` element.  When you try to iterate through the children of `report`, there's nothing there.

Instead of the second (inner) loop, simply do this:

```
$arr[$id][] = (string)$node;
```

When I did, I got the following result:

```
<pre>
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07-14-2015_DPLOH_SalesID_1.pdf
            [1] => 07-17-2015_DPLOH_SalesID_1.pdf
            [2] => 07-14-2015_DTE_SalesID_1.pdf
            [3] => 07-14-2015_IDT_SalesID_1.pdf
            [4] => 07-14-2015_Kratos_SalesID_1.pdf
            [5] => 07-14-2015_Spark_SalesID_1.pdf
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your script to work slightly differently:

```
$emp = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

$id  = intval($emp['salesid']);
$arr = array(
    $id         => array(),
);

$lst = $emp->xpath('/emp/report');

while (list(, $text) = each($lst))
{  
    $arr[$id][] = (string) $text;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Cheers